# How do I SSH to molecule instance without molecule login

Tags: ssh, centos, vagrant, molecule

I'm using molecule and vagrant to deploy centos7 instance. For some reasons, I need to use ssh command access molecule instance, `instead of molecule login`. The ssh informations will then paste into one of my VS code extension.

**Molecule.yml**

```
---

dependency:
  name: gilt
driver:
  name: vagrant
  provider:
    name: virtualbox
lint:
  name: yamllint
platforms:
  - name: openresty-instance
    box: centos/7
    instance_raw_config_args:
      - "ssh.insert_key = false"
      - "vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 22, host: 22"
      - "vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 80, host: 8080"
    interfaces:
      - auto_config: true
        network_name: private_network
        ip: '192.168.33.111'
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  log: true
  lint:
    name: ansible-lint
verifier:
  name: testinfra
  lint:
    name: flake8
```

The IP above let me access port 80 outside vagrant.

But the ssh command to molecule instance IP is not working.

**Error**

> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @
>   WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
>   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ IT IS
>   POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY! Someone could be
>   eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)! It is also
>   possible that a host key has just been changed. The fingerprint for
>   the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
>   SHA256:wVk4Da5pWWNHLiypvEKAJuwzG/2FLOMgwPkrO4oFBZQ. Please contact
>   your system administrator. Add correct host key in
>   /Users/abel/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
>   Offending ECDSA key in /Users/abel/.ssh/known_hosts:32 ECDSA
>   host key for 192.168.33.111 has changed and you have requested strict
>   checking. Host key verification failed

Comment: According to me your Q&A is more on-topic on [DevOps SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions). SO and SF are about software and system engineering respectively.

Comment: Remove the offending key in /Users/abel/.ssh/known_host. You will have to do this every time you re-create a vm with the same IP.

Answer (score 0):

This message can mean what it says: "that there is something nasty going on" if you have this in an environment with static servers.

But if you have, say, a testing-environment, where you create and destroy virtual machines as a daily procedure, this is a "normal" security warning.

It just means "hey, I now this guy, but his fingerprint doesn't match the one in my document archive". If this is intended (like I said, in a test-environment) - then just go into the "document archive", delete "this guys fingerprint" and "take a new fingerprint of him".

So in your case ("/Users/abel/.ssh/known_hosts:32") just open your "known_hosts"-file, and delete the line 32.

Or use the command:

`ssh-keygen -R 192.168.33.111 -f "~/Users/abel/.ssh/known_hosts"`